# Excel Formulae needed to calculate weight loss

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Myself and some friends are taking part in a weight loss challenge this year and I will be recording monthly weigh in's and body measurements.  I need to find a calculation which will work out the difference's in inches and pounds.

I have the item title in column B from row 10 down to Row 17.  The first one in Row 10 is weight which is calculated in pounds.

Then going across from Column C is the month starting with Jan ending in December in Column N.

The total loss needs to be updated after every monthly entry into column O.

Unfortunately I cannot post a picture of the table as I'm new to this group.

I've tried other formulaes suggested to people with similar problems but they don't work for me.

Can anyone help?

Many Thanks
Helen

Comment: So, B10-17 are weight values and C0-N0 contains Jan-Dec?

Answer (score 1):

Bit hard to work it out from your description but I think you are looking for

```
=C10-MIN(D10:N10)
```

That assumes the largest figure will always be in column C and will update every time a new entry is placed in the row.

If the weight might go up (not that you are going to fail the challenge) you could use

```
=C10 - LOOKUP(1,1/(D10:N10<>""),D10:N10)
```

Comment: This only works if the weight goes down every month.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. (And you can copy down to other rows as necessary)

```
=INDEX(C10:N10,1,COUNT(C10:N10))-C10
```

`INDEX` used here, returns the value from the range `C10:N10` in the first and only row, where the column is determined by the count of values already entered. So if you have values entered for 4 months, the formula will take April's value and subtract January's value.

A negative number will represent weight loss. A positive number means weight gain.

Answer (score -2):

Total fat loss :

(AVERAGE(C10:N10) - C10)*2

Comment: `MOY` isn't a formula in Excel

Comment: i was meaning average.